# How do I unsummon Gooey?

Tags: kirbys-dream-land-3

I accidentally sacrificed some of my health to summon Gooey as an AI controlled partner. Is there a way to dismiss Gooey so I can go back to playing solo?

[image: Kirby and Gooey]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to [swallow him](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Kirby%27s_Dream_Land_3/Characters#Gooey) instead so that he gets removed from the gameplay.

> Kirby can still call out Gooey even if he has next to no health, and swallowing Gooey replenishes two units of health too, meaning that Gooey can be exploited to gain free health when you're almost dying.